# What is the slope of $x^3+y^3 = 9$ at $(2,1)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is (verbatim):

> What is the slope of $x^3+y^3 = 9$ at $(2,1)$

Secondly, I am confused about how the differentiating carries out. If I differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, I get
$$
3x^2 + 3y^2 \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = -x^2/y^2 = -4
$$

But if I try to rearrange the given equation first to get $y$ on the LHS, I get
$$
x^3+y^3 = 9 \\
y^3 = 9 - x^3 \\
y = (9 - x^3)^{1/3} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = 1/3 * (9 - x^3)^{-2/3} * -3x^2 = -x^2 (9 - x^3)^{-2/3}
$$

But now this derivative no longer depends on $y$. What is the issue with the second approach?

Comment: There's no problem with the second approach. Note that $y^{-2} = (9 - x^3)^{-2/3}$, so you get the same thing.

Comment: Both approaches are fine. I think you made a silly mistake in your first approach and wrote down $4$ instead of $-4$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Ah I see. What is the point of saying to find the slope at (2,1) instead of just at $x = 2$? The $y = 1$ seems unnecessary?

Comment: @AlanAbraham Yes, I did. I just changed it.

Comment: @AlanAbraham Good question! In this case, there's little point except to make it easier to find the corresponding $y$-value. In general, the curve defined may not be a function of $x$ (or $y$), in which case multiple $y$ values could correspond to a given $x$-value. For example, if it were $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ instead, then both $(3, 4)$ and $(3, -4)$ are different points on the curve, with different derivatives.